# How to delete polygons less than a certain area?

Tags: qgis

I'm trying to delete all polygons with an area smaller than a certain give value. Is this possible in qgis?

The goal here is to delete all the islands off a map.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

So I figured it out

1. vector-> geometry tools->Export/Add geometry columns
2. right click on the layer that you added the geometry columns and select `query`
3. enter `"AREA"  > SOME VALUE` and click `ok`
4. right click on the the layer you just queried and choose `save as` and that is the final file

Answer (score 1):

If you are looking to delete the polygons, then you will want to have an attribute with area.  In an editing session, query the field where areas is less than 'X'.  With the polygons selected, delete the records (red circle with the X).  Save the editing session and stop the editing session.  This will permanently delete the records from the file.

Answer (score 1):

An easy way if you have an area field in your attribute table is to just control click on the area field and sort ascending and drag and highlight all polygons you want to delete, you can try and avoid deleting landlocked small polygons with this method.

There's also probably a functionality similar to or the same as calculate geometry in ArcGIS which will generate the Area data and populate the fields of your attribute table with it.

Comment: Doesn't work if features are multipolygons

Answer (score 0):

In QGIS 3.28.9, you can use `Toolbox > Vector selection > Extract by attribute` to select the polygons you wish to keep / discard as shown here:

[image]